# Change visibility of button in gridview for different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview of comments which shows a delete button for the comment made by logged in user.I mean logged in uder can delete his own comments ONLY.
I have tried the below but it doesnt show the delete button for any user.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="540px" ShowHeader="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="CommentId">
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            ---No comments on this event---
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table style="width:540px;background-color:white">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:60px" rowspan="3">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgUser" Width="50px" Height="50px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ProfilePicPath") %>' runat="server" style="border: 2px inset #C0C0C0" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:480px;border-bottom:solid 1px #999999">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentator" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' style="color: #336699"></asp:Label>
                                        &nbsp;on
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CommentTime") %>' style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:480px;vertical-align:top">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:480px;vertical-align:top;text-align:right">
                                        &nbsp;<asp:HiddenField ID="hfUserId" Value='<%# Bind("UserId") %>' runat="server" />
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Visible='<%# Session["UserId"] == Eval("UserId") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CommentId")%>' CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SportsActiveConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spExtractEventComments" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Eventid" Type="Int32" ControlID="lblEventId" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you can see above, i am comparing the current user(stored in session) to the UserId of that comment.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Visible='<%# Session["UserId"] == Eval("UserId") %>'.....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UserID` can be any number (1,5,144,...)?

Comment: @nelek - UserId is nvarchar...something like PL00124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is example :

```
vb.net :
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Visible='<%# If(Session("UserId") = Eval("UserId"), "True", "False")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

c# (I think) :
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Visible='<%# If(Session["UserId"] == Eval("UserId").ToString() ? true : false)%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Using `If` for checking are values match (Tested and working)

*`If(condition,do what You want if result is True, do what You want if result if False)`*

Comment: Well, thank you. This worked                                                              <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Visible='<%# Session["UserId"].ToString() == Eval("UserId").ToString()? true:false %>'

Comment: Yes, that is. I'm weak with c# so I just convert from vb.net using online convertors.

Comment: @MukeshPanwar Please mark this answer if it helped you so other developers don't waste their time to read your question again.